# ASP.NET - How to load a model with data from another model that is twice removed via 2 foreign keys

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble figuring this one out.

I have 3 tables, each linked by foreign key. JobDescription, TrainingMatrix, and Document

I used EF scaffolding to build the model and controllers for these three tables.

Job Description Model:

```
public partial class JobDescription
{
    public JobDescription()
    {
        JobPositions = new HashSet<JobPosition>();
        TrainingMatrices = new HashSet<TrainingMatrix>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name="ID")]
    public int JobDescId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Job Position Document")]
    public string DocId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Position Document")]
    public Document Doc { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobPosition> JobPositions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TrainingMatrix> TrainingMatrices { get; set; }

}
```

Training Matrix Model

```
public partial class TrainingMatrix
{
    public string DocId { get; set; }
    public int JobDescId { get; set; }

    public Document Doc { get; set; }
    public JobDescription JobDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Document Model

```
public partial class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        TrainingMatrices = new HashSet<TrainingMatrix>();
        TrainingRecords = new HashSet<TrainingRecord>();
    }

    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public string DocId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Vault Location")]
    public string VaultLocation { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public ICollection<JobDescription> JobDescriptions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TrainingMatrix> TrainingMatrices { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TrainingRecord> TrainingRecords { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make a view within a view. 
I'm trying to put the training matrix view inside of the job description details view.

Job Description View

```
@model PTI.Web.EPDM.TrainingInterface.Models.JobDescription

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Job Description</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @switch (Model.Status)
            {
                case "A":
                    <text>Active</text>
                    break;
                case "O":
                    <text>Obsolete</text>
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Doc)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Doc.DocId)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/TrainingMatrices/Index.cshtml", Model.TrainingMatrices, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)); }
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.JobDescId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

TrainingMatrix View

```
@model IEnumerable<PTI.Web.EPDM.TrainingInterface.Models.TrainingMatrix>

@{

}

<h2>Related Documents</h2>

<table id="documentTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Doc.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Doc.VaultLocation)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Doc.Type)

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doc.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doc.VaultLocation)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(item.Doc.Type != null)
                    {
                    switch (item.Doc.Type)
                    {
                        case "FC":
                            <text>Form Control</text>
                            break;
                        case "AI":
                            <text>Action Item</text>
                            break;
                        case "WI":
                            <text>Work Instruction</text>
                            break;
                        case "CC":
                            <text>Customer Complaint</text>
                            break;
                        case "SOP":
                            <text>Standard Operating Procedure</text>
                            break;
                        case "JP":
                            <text>Job Position</text>
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.DocId" title="Details">
                        <i class="fas fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#documentTable').DataTable();

    });
</script>
```

When run by itself, the Training Matrix view loads up correctly, displaying all of the document info for the training matrix, because it is running the controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var applicationDbContext = _context.TrainingMatrices.Include(t => t.Doc).Include(t => t.JobDesc);
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

But when running from the Job Description page as a partial view using this controller it crashes, because JobDescription.TrainingMatrices.Doc does not exist, and throws a NullReferenceException:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ViewData["DocId"] = new SelectList(_context.Documents.Where(d => d.Status == "A"), "DocId", "Title");

    JobDescription jobDescription = await _context.Descriptions
        .Include(j => j.Doc)
        .Include(j=>j.TrainingMatrices)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.JobDescId == id);


    if (jobDescription == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    ViewData["JobDescId"] = jobDescription.JobDescId;
    return View(jobDescription);
}
```

What I need to do, is either get the JobDescription controller to populate the JobDescription.TrainingMatrices.Doc values, or have the partial view call the TrainingMatricesController

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is confusing to me, but if I understand correctly, try:

```
JobDescription jobDescription = await _context.Descriptions
    .Include(j => j.Doc)
    .Include(j=>j.TrainingMatrices)
           .ThenInclude(t => t.Doc)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.JobDescId == id);
```

Comment: Beautiful. That's exactly the command I was looking for. THANKS!